# Adding different times in php

Tags: php, time, addition

Hello just a simple question here.
Php's time related functions are confusing me ;-(

Given 2 variables

```
$start = "2013-07-25 20:24:13" ('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$duration = "0:55" ('H:i');
```

How may I add `$duration` to `$start`? should result in:

> "2013-07-25 21:19:13"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php

Comment: Things would probably be infinitely less confusing if you only used timestamps except for when you need to display the date.

Comment: In addition to the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+add+date+php

Comment: That's wat I came up with:<code>
    $start = strtotime($start);
    $duration = explode(':', $duration);
    $end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+'.$duration[0].' hour '.$duration[1].' minutes', $start));</code>

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DatePeriod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-07-25 20:24:13');
$dt->add(new DatePeriod('P55M'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: + Beat me. Note that the DateTime class is available in PHP 5.3+.

Comment: If people are still using 5.2 and developing new projects in it they should somewhat stop it @JasonMcCreary. Hell even 5.3 will be EOL next year.

Comment: @PeeHaa, totally agree. Added for thoroughness.

Comment: $dt->add(new DatePeriod('P55M'));
does not work because $duration is dynamic an can also be 1:15

Comment: @TNT_Larsn You'll need to convert that into hours and minutes which is easy to do (`explode()`). The above example just shows you how to do the math.